# Trouble running Flask in Apache/CGI

Tags: python, cgi, flask

I have a shared hosting from Namecheap ( No ssh access). There I can run any python file in the CGI-bin directory when I type the full path including the .py extension. I want to know how to run a flask app in such an environment. Should I change the .htaccess or make a .cgi or fcgi or wsgi? I am not sure what these are or what they do. If someone can explain these too.

Comment: I guess your app is available via something like ``http://example.com/cgi-bin/my_app.py``?

Comment: Yes that's right. I can run a simple hello world! program.

Comment: And you want it to run under ``http://example.com/``?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259435/deploy-flask-application-on-11-shared-hosting-with-cgi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/cgi/

If your CGI-app is available at `http://example.com/cgi-bin/myapp.py`, you have to put the following in a `.htaccess` (assuming you're using Apache) to make the app available at `http://example.com/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # Don't interfere with static files
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /cgi-bin/myapp.py/$1 [L]
```